# How to wrap SKPaymentQueue in Rx Observable

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, rx-swift

Does anyone know how you'd go about wrapping [SKPaymentQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/) in an Rx Observable? SKPaymentQueue requires that you register an observer that conforms to the [SKPaymentTransactionObserver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)SKPaymentTransactionObserver) via the [SKPaymentQueue.addTransactionObserver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/addTransactionObserver:) method.

So far I've tried the following but it doesn't work. I suspect because the observer proxy is getting deallocated before it's called. It feels like I'm missing some kind of idiomatic Rx trick here:

```
class StoreService {
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue()

    func purchase(product: SKProduct) -> Observable<SKProduct> {
        return Observable.create { (observer) in
            let transactionObserver = PaymentTransactionProxyObserver(observer)

            self.paymentQueue.addTransactionObserver(transactionObserver)

            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            self.paymentQueue.addPayment(payment)

            return AnonymousDisposable {
                self.paymentQueue.removeTransactionObserver(transactionObserver)
            }
        }
    }
}

class PaymentTransactionProxyObserver: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    let observer: AnyObserver<SKPaymentTransaction>

    init(_ observer: AnyObserver<SKPaymentTransaction>) {
        self.observer = observer
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            observer.onNext(transaction)
        }
        observer.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

I've also hunted around in the RxCocoa source looking for inspiration however the closest example, the [NSNotificationCenter](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/Common/Observables/NSNotificationCenter%2BRx.swift) extension, uses a closure as opposed to an observer with multiple callback methods an a register and unregister step. It also doesn't seem to fit the DelegateProxy pattern used by other extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your proxy is getting deleted too quickly. `PaymentTransactionProxyObserver` needs to hold a reference to itself to keep itself alive and then nul that reference after it calls `onCompleted`.

Here's a gist for inspiration. It uses Promises instead of Rx, but it should help you get the idea. When looking at this code think of PromiseKit's `fulfill` method as `observer.onNext; observer.onCompleted` and PromiseKit's `reject` as `observer.onError`.

https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/b92163d6055e1a580d493676e5b1e448